# nppExec: file coudn't be found

Tags: notepad++, nppexec

i try to execute a ruby file with nppExec (notepad++) but it tells me that the file couldn't be found:

`Error opening script file: D:/Eigene (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)`

One directory has a space in its name. Without the space it works, but i would have to change a lot of files.

i had the same problem also with the run command

`cmd /K jruby "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`,

but with

`cmd /K "cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" && jruby "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)""`

it worked. Even adding the `cd` to nppExec and activating `FOLLOW $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)` didn't help.

This occurs under Windows 7 x64. With x86 there wasn't this problem

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you can run `cmd /K jruby <ruby-filename>` from command prompt regardless of directory you are positioned at. You might need to check environment PATH variable to achieve global visiblity of ruby executable.

Generally the rule is: **if you can run something from the command prompt regardless of directory, you can run the same from NPPExec**. Therefore I recommend testing the command with command prompt first, then adapt it to NPPExec.